# jquery click event for a class starting with same initial name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-click-event

I have multiple divs added dynamically. The class name is given as "result_"+id  where the id is from database table.

```
<div class="result_137">Gaurab Dahal</div>
<div class="result_138">saurab dahal</div>
```

---

[image]

How can I write the click event so that it can adddress the div on which it is clicked.

for example I can write the css like below to address all the divs that has classname starting with the string "result".

```
div[class^="result"]{
    padding:5px;
    width:490px;
    background: rgba(204,204,204,0.5);
    font: 12px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For dynamically added div you need to us [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding event. You can delegate event to doucment or to parent element of dynamically added elements.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/yPwfc/1/)**

```
$(document).on('click', 'div[class^=result]', function(){
    alert($(this).text());                              
});
```

Comment: i tried that too but that didn't work.. i tried with a simple alert message.

Comment: You need to use on instead of click to bind events with dynamically added elements.

Answer (score 3):

As you have dynamically added divs so:

```
$(function(){    // ready handler required
    $(document).on('click', 'div[class^=result]', function(){ // .on in your case
        alert($(this).text());                               // will be helpful
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get id of div like this `var selection = $(ev.target).attr("id");` where ev is event and then u can apply click function of jquery like this `$(selection).live('click',function(){//ur code here });`